# How to edit docx using Java

Tags: java, docx, docx4j

I need replace cerain words or phrases in docx-file and save it with another name. I know that my problem is not unik and I tried find solution in the web. But I still can't get a result that I need.

I found two ways to solwe my task but came to the deadlock in each case.
1. Unfold docx like a zip-file, change xml with main content and pack into archive again. But after that manipulations I can't open new changed docx in MS Word. It is odd because I can do the similar steps by hands (without Java, using WinRar) and get a correct result file.
So can you explain me how to archive docx content to get a correct file using Java?

2. Using external API. I get an advice to use docx4j Java library. But all tat I can with it is just replace a label (like ${label}) in template with any words (I used [VariableReplace](https://github.com/plutext/docx4j/blob/master/src/samples/docx4j/org/docx4j/samples/VariableReplace.java) sample). But I want change words that I want without using a template with labels.

I hope for a help.

Comment: Did you try apache-poi?

Answer (score 4):

I had this code. I hope that it helps you to resolve your problem. With it, you can read from a .docx find the word that you would change. Change this word and save the new paragraphs in new document.

```
 //WriteDocx.java
   import org.apache.poi.xwpf.extractor.XWPFWordExtractor;
   import org.apache.poi.xwpf.usermodel.*;
   import java.io.*;
   import java.util.ArrayList;
   import java.util.List;
   import java.util.StringTokenizer;

   public class WriteDocx
   {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        int count = 0;
        XWPFDocument document = new XWPFDocument();
        XWPFDocument docx = new XWPFDocument(new FileInputStream("Bonjour1.docx"));
        XWPFWordExtractor we = new XWPFWordExtractor(docx);
        String text = we.getText() ;
        if(text.contains("SMS")){
            text = text.replace("SMS", "sms");
            System.out.println(text);
        }
        char[] c = text.toCharArray();
        for(int i= 0; i < c.length;i++){

            if(c[i] == '\n'){
                count ++;
            }
        }
        System.out.println(c[0]);
        StringTokenizer st = new StringTokenizer(text,"\n");

        XWPFParagraph para = document.createParagraph();
        para.setAlignment(ParagraphAlignment.CENTER);
        XWPFRun run = para.createRun();
        run.setBold(true);
        run.setFontSize(36);
        run.setText("Apache POI works well!");

        List<XWPFParagraph>paragraphs = new ArrayList<XWPFParagraph>();
        List<XWPFRun>runs = new ArrayList<XWPFRun>();
        int k = 0;
        for(k=0;k<count+1;k++){
            paragraphs.add(document.createParagraph());
        }
        k=0;
        while(st.hasMoreElements()){
            paragraphs.get(k).setAlignment(ParagraphAlignment.LEFT);
            paragraphs.get(k).setSpacingAfter(0);
            paragraphs.get(k).setSpacingBefore(0);
            run = paragraphs.get(k).createRun();
            run.setText(st.nextElement().toString());
            k++;
        }

        document.write(new FileOutputStream("test2.docx"));
    }          
   }
```

PS: XWPFDocument docx = new XWPFDocument(new FileInputStream("Bonjour1.docx"))

You must change  "Bonjour1.docx" with the name of file from where you would replace    certain words or phrases.
I use [APACHE POI library](http://www.eu.apache.org/dist/poi/release/bin/) 
And I take some code from this site [HANDLING MS WORD DOCUMENTS USING APACHE POI](http://developeriq.in/articles/2012/jul/03/handling-ms-word-documents-using-apache-poi/)

UPDATE
[image]

Comment: Which jar file did you used for this?

Comment: I used this JAR:   poi-3.11-20141221.jar, poi-excelant-3.11-20141221.jar, poi-ooxml-3.11-20141221.jar, poi-ooxml-3.11-schemas-20141221.jar, poi-scartchpad-3.11-20141221.jar, xmlbeans-2.6.0.jar,

Comment: Hii .. how can we make these changes but conserving the style of document at the same time??

Answer (score 0):

If you want to change arbitrary words, you can do that easily enough with docx4j.

But first you need to find them.

You can find your words using an [XPath query](https://github.com/plutext/docx4j/blob/master/src/samples/docx4j/org/docx4j/samples/XPathQuery.java), or by [traversing the document tree](https://github.com/plutext/docx4j/blob/master/src/main/java/org/docx4j/samples/OpenMainDocumentAndTraverse.java) in Java.

Comment: Links are not working. Answer is not useful now.